# Связь php с desktop приложением

Tags: php, desktop

Подскажите какими способами можно организовать связь desktop приложения (клиента) и php.
Например.

у меня есть скрипт index.php:

```
<?php
echo 'Text ot servera';
?>
```

Мне нужно desktop приложением обратиться к странице index.php и получить строку Text ot servera. Как передать так данные через json или xml?

Comment: @Asen, извините не сдержался, но меня просто бесит от таких **абсолютно пренебрежительно-бессодержательных** комментариев и ответов.

Если знаете, что читать - дайте **конкретную** ссылку или **образец** гугл запроса.

--

Правильно на Вас тут кое-кто взъелся.

Comment: @Asen, вот и объясните ТС ваше видение вопроса.

Кстати, можно ведь получить локальный ответ и по другому. Например, вызвать интерпретатор *php* с интересующим файлом. И никакого сервера.

Подумайте.

Comment: А кто говорит про простую задачу? Может человеку нужно изначально понять как получить и отдать контент, а ПО у него будет потом стоить кучу бабла, и все тут будут сидеть и слюни пускать!

Comment: Комментарии @Asen пропали. Видимо из-за бана. 

@ХэщКод, так и было задумано в проекте форума ?

Comment: @avp он сам все удалил
А мило смотрится мордашка да?

![alt text][1]
 [1]: http://i.imgur.com/G1c67.png

Comment: Класс !!!!

Comment: Да не, @Asen реально помогал решать проблемы, хоть изредка и нес ересь, но помощь от него была существенна, имхо)

Comment: <pre>осмелюсь спросит на чем вы планируете реализовать десктопную часть ?
В виде службы ? или же "user friendly interface" ? в потоках ? Как оно (десктопная часть) должен общаться с php  скриптом ?</pre>

Answer (score 4):

Согласен с [@avp](/users/232/avp)

> Почитайте книжки, прежде чем лезть непонятно куда. В любом учебнике похожая задача рассматривается.

Многие уже писали, что либо пройди этот вопрос мимо, либо хоть ссылку дай на тему где можно почитать.

А по вопросу.
Ну во первых где валяется php? на сервере с апачем? если да, то обратиться к странице можно по её адресу http://localhost/somepage.php и получить ответ на экран 
    Text ot servera

> Text ot servera. Как передать так данные через json или xml?

Передать данные в каком направлении? К серверу или от сервера?

Если к серверу, то либо GET либо POST. Получить данные, опять же, смотря какие и как их отдавать нужно. Просто показать, или показать в определенном формате, или отдать их нужно.

Собственно вопрос откорректировать в лучшую сторону советую, больше конструктива!

Comment: Это были слова забаненного @Asen:

      Почитайте книжки, прежде чем лезть непонятно куда. В любом учебнике похожая задача рассматривается.

Answer (score -1):

[Гляньте в эту сторону, проще будет](http://develstudio.ru/)